# Log errors into raising error during delete

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use the LOG ERRORS INTO in my DML for deleting an object.

```
create table av_parent( id number primary key, name  varchar2(20));
create table av_child (id number primary key, p_id  number, foreign key(p_id) references av_parent(id) );

insert into av_parent values (1,'a');
insert into av_parent values (2,'sa');
insert into av_parent values (3,'af');
insert into av_parent values (4,'ah');

insert into av_child values (11,1);
insert into av_child values (12,2);

BEGIN
  DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 'av_parent');
end;
/
select * from err$_av_parent;
delete from av_parent where id=1 LOG ERRORS INTO err$_av_parent ('DELETE') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Here, when I delete, the error message "ORA-02292: integrity constraint (XYZ.SYS_C00848165) violated - child record found
" is inserted into the log table.

I now add a trigger on delete but does nothing

```
create or replace trigger t_av_parent
before  delete
on av_parent
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
for each row
begin
  null;
  end;
```

When I delete with the same command, the error pops up and is not inserted into the log table.

```
delete from av_parent where id=1 LOG ERRORS INTO err$_av_parent ('DELETE') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This looks like bug 18495911. I can reproduce in 11.2.0.4 but only with a `for each row` trigger, so I guess there's some conflict in the order constraints and triggers interact with error logging. Seems to still exist in 12c from the notes on that bug report.

Comment: Yes, it happens in 12c too. But, surprisingly update works despite having trigger on after update.

Comment: After-update and before-update triggers fire at different points though; if there was a constraint violation I wouldn't expect it to reach the after trigger anyway, I think. But, the bug seems to be specific to delete, so an update with a before-update-for-each-row might also still work as expected.